# Which version of gem is used when there is no Gemfile

Tags: ruby

There is similar question here.
[Ruby: Rails: Which version of a gem is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141206/ruby-rails-which-version-of-a-gem-is-used)

But it's about when `Gemfile` is used.

I want to know if there is no Gemfile, which version of gem is used.

For example I have 4 versions of `selenium-webdriver` in my system.

```
 % gem list | grep selenium
selenium-webdriver (2.53.0, 2.48.1, 2.46.2, 2.45.0)
```

And I just use it by `pry` and `require 'selenium-webdriver`. How can I know which version is used? Only the latest is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have more than one gem because each project with Gemfile in your machine have one different version of it.

When using the gem via `require` or command line without specifying the version the last one - the greater version - will be automatically used.

By convention, in the most part of the cases, you can print the version  doing the following:

```
require 'some_gem'
puts SomeGem::VERSION
# => "3.0.3"
```

Comment: Thanks, so `2.53.0` is used in my case, right? It seems `selenium-webdriver` don't follow the convention. I couldn't find the `VERSION` constant.